# How can I simply use Ant Colony Optimization to find the minimum value of a function?

Tags: python, ant-colony

I want to use Ant Colony Optimization to find the minimum value of a function like 2x^2-5y^2.
But I do not know how to implement it using ant colony. Can Anyone give me a simple example?

Answer (score 1):

You're optimizing space denoted by 2 variables: `x` and `y`, so these values are your solution. Fitness of that solution is your function. Though I don't think ACO is well suitable for continous space. Better start with vanilla PSO. You can find tutorial [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/implementing-particle-swarm-optimization-pso-algorithm-in-python-9efc2eb179a6).